# Need Help Configuring VTK-m Build (cmake) on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, vtk, glut, glew

I have tried three times to build, and install, VTK-m, with cmake, and each time it has crashed my computer when I run `make -j`, so I really need help from a human at this point because I'm getting worried about all the hard resets this is putting my system through, and I'm about to lose my mind at what I'm seeing.

First, I run `ccmake path/to/source` to configure and generate the build files. Here is the first pass of what that looks like:

```
Page 1 of 1
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS               *ON
BUILD_TESTING                   *ON
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE                *Release
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX            */usr/local
VTKm_ENABLE_BENCHMARKS          *ON
VTKm_ENABLE_CPACK               *ON
VTKm_ENABLE_CUDA                *ON
VTKm_ENABLE_DOCUMENTATION       *OFF
VTKm_ENABLE_EXAMPLES            *ON
VTKm_ENABLE_HDF5_IO             *ON
VTKm_ENABLE_KOKKOS              *OFF
VTKm_ENABLE_MPI                 *ON
VTKm_ENABLE_OPENMP              *ON
VTKm_ENABLE_RENDERING           *ON
VTKm_ENABLE_TBB                 *OFF
VTKm_ENABLE_TESTING             *ON
VTKm_ENABLE_TUTORIALS           *ON
VTKm_INSTALL_EXAMPLES           *ON
VTKm_USE_64BIT_IDS              *ON
VTKm_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION       *ON
VTKm_Vectorization              *none
enable_sanitizers               *OFF
python                          *OFF
```

Then, I press `c`, for configure, and after finding HDF5, CUDA, OpenMP, etc., I get the above, but with some expanded fields, e.g., where all the HDF5 stuff is, what the CUDA architecture is, blah blah blah. Here is where the first problem appears:

```
GLEW_DIR                        *GLEW_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

This throws me for a loop because when I run,

```
~$ echo $GLEW_DIR
/usr
```

or do any other kind of investigation into the state of the OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library on my system, everything appears to be situated properly. I've tried setting this field manually, and continuing. That yields the following,

```
 Could not use git to determine source version, using version 2.1.0
 CMake Deprecation Warning at CMake/VTKmDeviceAdapters.cmake:121 (message):
   VTKm_CUDA_Architecture used, use CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES instead in CMake
   >= 3.18
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMake/VTKmWrappers.cmake:14 (include)
   CMakeLists.txt:233 (include)

 Checking for module 'glut'
   No package 'glut' found
 Checking for module 'glut'
   No package 'glut' found
 Configuring done
```

Ignoring the warnings, the second problem is that The OpenGL Utility Toolkit (GLUT) can't be found. This throws me for a second loop because when I investigate the state of GLUT on my system, e.g., by seeing if it's installed with `sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev`, I am met with:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
freeglut3-dev is already the newest version (2.8.1-6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Expanding on the above, I've toggled into advanced mode during the configuration step to see as much detail as possible. There are some worrying fields, e.g., `HDF5_DIR` and `HDF5_DIFF_EXECUTABLE` are not found, but here are the relevant pieces relating to GLEW, and GLUT:

```
 GLEW_DIR                         GLEW_DIR-NOTFOUND
 GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR                 /usr/include  
 GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARY_DEBUG        GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND           
 GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARY_RELEASE      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so         
 GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG        GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND           
 GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.a          
 GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR                 /usr/include
 GLUT_Xi_LIBRARY                  GLUT_Xi_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
 GLUT_Xmu_LIBRARY                 GLUT_Xmu_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND                    
 GLUT_glut_LIBRARY                /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so
```

I expected that all of these fields would be filled in, because by all indications, everything is situated, but that's not the case.

At this point, I can configure as many times as I want to, but the result will be the same message as above about 'glut' not being found. If I decide to generate the build files, and then run `make -j`, my computer crashes around [12%] into the build process. I cannot retrieve exactly what is being built at the failure point, but it's something that involves TBB, I remember that much.